# Stuck using filecmp.dircmp to only show differing files

Tags: python

Currently using this, super simple;

```
import filecmp
import sys

dirpath1, dirpath2 = sys.argv[1:]

comparison = filecmp.dircmp(dirpath1, dirpath2)
print(comparison.report_full_closure())
```

What I'd like to do is only see (print) the files which are different in each sub directory 'Only in...' and not the 'Identical files'
It would also be good if I could define some file types to ignore
I'm struggling with the filecmp use resources I've found online and making no progress

Thank you

Comment: `comparison = dircmp(dirpath1, dirpath2) ; print(comparison.left_only + comparison.right_only)`

Comment: Hi - using the above I get an error 'dircmp' is not defined. If I modify to as follows

comparison = filecmp.dircmp(dirpath1, dirpath2) ; print(comparison.left_only + comparison.right_only)

then it runs, but it only seems to perform a comparison 1 sub directory level down. Any way to get it to keep going? With my original version it did the comparison all the way down (comparing the files in the sub directories)

Appreciate your input

Comment: Sometimes it's good to check *[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html)* of module you're using ;) Scroll to the bottom, there's a solution.

Comment: I think you credit me with more sense than I deserve! :) Only got this far copy and pasting online searches. Tried the solution at the bottom but it keeps throwing up errors. I think I'm probably supposed to substitute some of the elements for meaningful paths on my machine? My intention is to use over and over, jumping around between directories, so keen to build in the expression(?) which allows me to select the directories at the start, each time the script is run. (Doing this on a MAC with 'Automator' tool and at the start of the application I'm defining the directories in finder)

Comment: Original script was working as intended but with the exception of showing me the 'identical files' as well as 'only in'